# Are questions about Storium on-topic?

Tags: discussion

[Storium](https://storium.com/) is a recently funded [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/stlhood/storium-the-online-storytelling-game) now in beta.  I'll quote text from their site to illustrate its function:

> Storium is a web-based online game that you play with friends. It
>   works by turning writing into a multiplayer game. With just your
>   computer, tablet, or smartphone, you can choose from a library of
>   imaginary worlds to play in, or build your own. You create your
>   story’s characters and decide what happens to them. You can tell any
>   kind of story with Storium. The only limit is your imagination.
>
> Storium uses familiar game concepts inspired by card games,
>   role-playing games, video games, and more. In each Storium game, one
>   player is the narrator, and everyone else takes on the role of a
>   character in the story. The narrator creates dramatic challenges for
>   the other players to overcome. In doing so, they move the story
>   forward in a new direction. Everyone gets their turn at telling the
>   story.

As we PBeM/PbP and Roll20 questions are on topic, I figured to get a ruling out of the way whether questions about Storium (or the worlds in Storium) are on-topic, as I figure it will come up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Definitely!

We already have several [storium](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storium) questions, and none of them have had a thought towards closure. It's an RPG site and system that lines up with table top/PbP RPGs very well. It's the same audience.

The chat regulars even have a few games going on.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**

While Storium doesn't bill itself as a traditional "**RPG**" in my experience as a Storium user/player its similarities to existing systems like Fate make it a good fit for our site. The experience of playing Storium is very much one of playing an RPG. We've already had a few [storium](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storium) questions which I believe worked well for our format and seem to be well received enough that I believe Storium should be allowed on the site.

Comment: As a sidenote: No matter what they bill themselves as, Storium is most definitely an RPG. I mean, the second paragraph quoted above can be used as a *definition* of RPG.